# Spring Boot Preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Security in my web application. Now I have a /api/login endpoint and the frontend simply post username and password in request body to get an JWT.

But I'm constantly getting

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8081/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I already added @CrossOrigin(origins = "*",maxAge = 3600) on the controller class to solve cors problem so now http get works fine. But all post didn't work because of the preflight. I also tried

```java
.requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
```

and

```java
.and().cors();
```

in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but non of them solve the problem. What should I do next?

Here is the full configuration class:

```java
package com.cyf.myblogserver.config;

import com.cyf.myblogserver.component.JwtRequestFilter;
import com.cyf.myblogserver.service.BlogUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsUtils;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private BlogUserDetailsService BlogUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(BlogUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/articles").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().cors();
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using spring security have a global setup for your cors like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
         http.
         cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()                                                                
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
                .antMatchers("/Signup").hasRole("USER")
                .and() //add rest of your configurations
    }

    @Bean   
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3001")); //or add * to allow all origins
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")); //to set allowed http methods
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("custom-header1", "custom-header2"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration); 
        return source; 
    }
}
```

When you provide the configuration like this globally the code is much more cleaner also you could provide the configurations as you want it to be and it will be applicable to all controllers and it's methods. Make sure that spring auto configurations work , we are providing the cors configuration bean and enabling cors on the spring security so if auto configuration is working spring will automatically use the cors bean that we created with our configurations.

Comment: Thanks, adding global configuration like yours solves the problem!

Comment: Adding `http.cors()` did the trick for me.